# Why does the subset of rows that match a condition added by the rows that don't match a condition not add up to the total number of rows?

Tags: r, ensembl

I need to match the external gene names of a table I have called (which has 1,000,000 entries) with their respective ensemble gene IDs.

Here's a small subset of `df`:

| V1 | external_gene_name | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M0085 | A1BG | 1 |
| M0085 | SNX8 | 1 |

and here's a small subset of `ensembl_ids`:

| ensembl_gene_id | external_gene_name |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000288263 | GRK1 |
| ENSG00000291428 | BRSK2 |

I also included a line to see the number of entries in `external_gene_name` which do not have corresponding ensemble names. Here is my code:

```
merged_df <- merge(df, ensembl_ids, by = "external_gene_name")
elements_not_in <- df$external_gene_name[!(df$external_gene_name %in% ensembl_ids$external_gene_name)]
```

But what's confusing me is that when I add the number of rows in `merged_df` with that of `elements_not_in`, the total exceeds 1,000,000. Shouldn't the total be 1,000,000? I'm wondering if there's a flaw in my code.

Answer (score 4):

From a brief glance, the gap is not in your code but in your expectations. You're operating based on an assumption of 1:1 mapping between ENSG IDs and HGNC symbols (your `external_gene_name` attribute). In reality, multiple ENSG IDs will map to the same HGNC symbol so the merge will produce multiple rows per `external_gene_name` in the merge product. This is why you're seeing a total greater than the sum of number of unique entries when you compare the merge product + the anti-join result (i.e., the `elements_not_in` dataset) to the initial individual datasets.